# How to send email using curl, smtp and oauth2 token with office 365 email server?

Tags: c++, curl, oauth, smtp, office365

I followed the documentation [here](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-smtp) to send an email using curl from bash and the basic authentication. Now I'm very confused how to do the same with the OAuth 2.0 authentication because I don't know how to use the access token. Also, how can this be implemented using libcurl and c++?

Comment: If you haven't seen it, [CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER explained](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER.html) may help.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, it will be helpful for the implementation but is there any way to send an email in the same way as it can be done with the basic auhtnetication with the curl bash command?

Comment: I haven't done any emailing with `libcurl`. The only reason I knew about the option I mentioned above is that I have it on my [todo list](https://github.com/TedLyngmo/curl-Easy-cpp/blob/master/TODO) for a mini C++ wrapper for libcurl I wrote. The list has some links in it that might help (or perhaps raise even more questions - I didn't get that far myself).